# how can i get count of each age group using php

Tags: php

please check this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => 46-65
    [1] => 7-12|31-45
    [2] => 31-45
    [3] => 31-45
    [4] => 66+
    [5] => 18-30
    [6] => 46-65
    [7] => 13-17|46-65
```

Here i converted string to array then i got below array :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46-65
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7-12
            [1] => 31-45
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 66+
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46-65
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13-17
            [1] => 46-65
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46-65
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7-12
            [1] => 31-45
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
            [1] => 31-45
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 31-45
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 18-30
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 13-17
            [1] => 18-30
            [2] => 46-65
        )
}
```

I stored age group in string format because each row can be have multiple age group. after that i converted into array. 
How can i get count of each age group like 46-65 is 6 times 18-30 is 8 times.
HEre i want count of each age group

Comment: Your code has typos (you open array with `(` and close it with `}`) and you should describe how did you approach your problem an what error or missbehaviour did you find when doing it.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for that:

```
<?php
$selections = [/** your array here */];
$counted = [];

// Loop full list
foreach($selections as $selection) {

    // Loop age elements in list
    foreach ($selection as $age) {

        // If not already counted initialise age range
        if(!isset($counted[$age])) {
            $counted[$age] = 0;
        }

        // Increment age range
        $counted[$age]++;
    }
}

var_dump($counted);
```

Comment: No problem, if it helped help others by marking this as accepted so they can see the solution if they have a similar problem.

Comment: Can you explain what you did, Marvin. Code only answers are not very helpful to future folks. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understood tom problem. Try something like this.
This will return you a array with as key the groups and as value the number of times it has been met.
I used your second array or you already subdivided into sub array

```
$groups = [];
foreach($array as $subArray) {
  foreach ($subArray as $group) {
    if (isset($groups[$group])) {
      $groups[$group] += 1;
    } else {
      $groups[$group] = 1;
    }
  }
}
```